# Website not showing changes made

Tags: website

I have a website that I am uploading new files to. I successfully uploaded files via FTP. When I go to www.domain.com it shows the old site, but if I go to www.domain.com/index.html it shows my new site.

If it helps, I designed the new site with Adobe Muse and uploaded it via Muse.

How can I tell what's wrong, and how can I get www.domain.com to show the new site?

I don't have access to the server that the site is hosted on. I am just using a hosting company to host my website.

Comment: Maybe you happen to have index.htm? Can you check if www.domain.com/index.htm shows your old site?

Comment: index.htm shows just a blank page

Answer (score 0):

I did expereinced the similar situation a long time ago, the
problem was with the FTP uploading process, the hosting guys forced a modified
index.html every time I tried to upload new site.

it could also be a browser issue have you tried pressing ctrl+F5 after u see
old site ?

As a solution, have a backup and then delete all files on FTP, then upload
latest site

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your browsing data. On the History, Clear browsing data of "Cached Image and Files".

Also, you can try deleting your files on the live. Refresh the website. Then re-upload the new files.